# PowerShell CMDlet alternatives for user creation/adition

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use below powershell command by replacing **Net User** thats because Net User only support 20 character long user name only.

```
New-LocalUser -Name "UserName" -NoPassword
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member UserName
```

But these powershell commands only seems to be working on WIn10 & Win2016, not working on 2008 & 2012.

Comment: If the cmdlets are not available in older versions, consider updating. Using `[ADSI]` (actuallu a shortcut to System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry) as a work-around might work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Available cmdlets, are PowerShell version-specific.

> Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts This section contains the help
> topics for the Local Accounts cmdlets in Windows PowerShell.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/?view=powershell-5.1

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Cim_OPeratingSystem).Version
# Results
<#
10.0.19041
#>

$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
# Results
<#
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      19041  1 
#>

Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object Name -like '*local*'
# Results
<#
    Directory: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                         
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                         
Manifest   1.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts  {Add-LocalGroupMember, Disable-LocalUser, Enable-LocalUser, Get-LocalGroup, Get-LocalGroupMember, Get-...

#>

Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet '*localuser*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
CommandType Name              Version Source                            
----------- ----              ------- ------                            
Cmdlet      Disable-LocalUser 1.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts
Cmdlet      Enable-LocalUser  1.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts
Cmdlet      Get-LocalUser     1.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts
Cmdlet      New-LocalUser     1.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts
Cmdlet      Remove-LocalUser  1.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts
Cmdlet      Rename-LocalUser  1.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts
Cmdlet      Set-LocalUser     1.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts
#>
```

Those cmdlets are only in PowerShell v5x and Powershell Core, and that is not the default on WS2K12R2 and below, which are v4 and below.

You need to either upgrade to PSv5 on those servers, or download and install a module from the Microsoft [powershellgallery.com](https://www.powershellgallery.com/).

```
Find-Module -Name '*localUser*' | Format-Table -AutoSize

Version Name                Repository Description
------- ----                ---------- -----------
3.0     LocalUserManagement PSGallery  a module that performs various local user management functions
```